# Support Options for Bathroom Shower Glass Panel wider than 3 Feet

Tags: shower, glass

We're currently remodeling a bathroom remodel and were thinking of getting a 40-46 inches wide glass panel, but our GC's glass supplier let him/us know that (at least here in CA) everything wider than 3 feet must be supported on three sides & not 'only' on the wall & floor side of things.

The glass shop sent out one sample picture of a 'stubby' arm coming down from the ceiling and holding it on that far out / weakest side and edge of the panel, but that's not necessarily what I'd call easy on the eyes.

Does anyone have any *good* looking recommendations and suggestions? Subjectiveness of taste and '*good looking*' aside, I'd be curious what other options than an arm are out there.

Answer (score 0):

To meet the code, you have the arm or a solid wall panel coming down from the ceiling .  The other option is taking the glass all the way to the ceiling.

Your best bet is to ask the glass people if they have other options, since they are the ones that will have to install to meet the code.

Unfortunately codes do not take personal design tastes into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Would you happen to know what code / -section is the one that applies here? Just out of personal curiosity and also wondering if code says it has to go up / come down or can also go sidewards. And yeah, heading out to the glazier in a bit to see what else they have but what I was thinking / asking here regarding options is i.e. when looking at glass 'railings' for stairs/walkways, there's quite a visual variety of styles out there and hence wondering what others have used / installed

Comment: No , I don't know the code section. I'm in Fla.  These are questions you need to ask of your GC.